# HashSet<HashSet<int>> doesn't allow duplicate in Java but it does in C#

Tags: java, c#, data-structures

I was working on a problem which makes use of the fact that HashSet does not allow duplicate values. For this the solution in Java computes multiple `HashSet<int>` and adds them to `HashSet<HashSet<int>>` and finally returns the size. This way it gets all distinct combinations of HashSet.
When I tried to do this in C# I didn't get distinct HashSet. I debugged and can see two HashSet with same value. As can be seen in screenshot below.

[image]

So is there a way to get the same behavior in C# probably by using my own comparer or maybe even better without it. I tried to create my own compare method but HashSet doesn't have indexing so not sure how to compare two HashSets. Or it is something not possible in C#.
One thing I noticed is in Java the initialization is as follows:

```
Set shapes = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();
Set shape = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

Since there is no Set in C# my initialization is:

```
HashSet<HashSet<int>> shapes = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>();
HashSet<int> shape = new HashSet<int>();
```

Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: `new HashSet<int> { 1 } != new HashSet<int> { 1 }` - this are 2 different objects, so they can be in one hashset

Comment: Both of your Java examples are **raw types**. Don't use raw types.

Comment: The c# interface for sets is `ISet<T>`.  Which is a moot point since you should be using the `var` keyword anyway... in both languages if you're using a Java compiler that's at least Java 10 compatible.

Comment: So Java's HashSet implements equals and hashCode, but C#'s doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make your own `EqualityComparer`, though it will likely not be the most efficient approach

**Example**

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<int>>
{
   public bool Equals(HashSet<int> x, HashSet<int> y)
      => x?.SetEquals(y) ?? false;

   public int GetHashCode(HashSet<int> obj)
   {
      unchecked
      {
         return obj.Aggregate(17, (current, item) => current * 31 + item.GetHashCode());
      }
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var rand = new Random();

var hashes = Enumerable.Range(0, 20)
                       .Select(x => new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
                                           .Select(y => rand.Next(0, 5))));


var hashList = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>(hashes, new MyComparer()) ;

foreach (var list in hashList)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",list));
```

**Output**

```
2, 0
3, 1
0, 1, 4
0, 2, 1
0, 3
4, 0, 3
4, 3
0, 1
1, 2
4, 3, 1
2, 1, 0
2
3, 1, 4
3, 2
4, 1, 3
0, 2
1, 4
1, 3
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4VBoxQ)

Comment: awesome that works.. now I need to sit back and understand how your code works.. :) I tried to use HashSet<List<int>> but by default that doesn't work either. Looks like for any reference type I will need my own comparer. Thanks..

Comment: @AnjaniKumarAgrawal you could make the comparer generic

Comment: Are you certain that your `GetHashCode` method works as expected? The hash computation depends on the order of items in the table, which can depend on insertion order, or even the size of the backing array.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference is that the Java `HashSet` `equals` method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals(java.lang.Object) compares the contents of the container.

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the given set is contained in this set. This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Set interface.

The .NET `HashSet` inherits its `Equals` method from `Object`. For reference types, `Object.Equals` simply checks for reference equality: that the two references passed to the method are in fact references to the same object in memory.

In C#, if you were to write:

```
var x = new HashSet<int>{2,3,4,5};
var y = new HashSet<int>{2,3,4,5};
var isEqual = x.Equals(y);
```

The value of `isEqual` will be `False` because `x` and `y` are two different objects. The equivalent code in Java will produce a value of `True` for `isEqual` because the comparison checks the contents.

The solution, as Michael Randall pointed out in his answer, is to supply your own comparer.

Comment: Yes and we can use SetEquals instead. { var isEqual = x.SetEquals(y);  } This give true.